# How to read json files that are larger than 2gb with node js?

Tags: node.js, json, bson

My goal is to index an entire food product database from https://world.openfoodfacts.org/data . I have downloaded entire database in mongodb BSON format, I have loaded it to mongodb compass and exported only essential fields:

- id
- product_name
- nutrients

I have been left with a json file that is about **3GB** in size.

The reason I want to read the file is to transform and change naming conventions of **nutrients** object that fits my database style.

I have tried to do the following:

```
fs.readFile(
  "/Users/chx/Downloads/dump/off/products.json",
  "utf8",
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(data[0]);
  }
);
```

I get the following error:

```
RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (2805202321) is greater than 2 GiB
```

How can I read and transform my data array?

Comment: Try to use streams: https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/nodejs-streams/

Comment: Since you have the data in a database already, why not [connect to the database with Node](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#connect-to-mongodb), fetch records, transform them, then save them, [one by one](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/#for-each-functional-iteration)? This removes the need to export, import, parse and write a large file.

Comment: @RickN are there any memory limitations that way? Can I fetch 2gb worth of data and transform it like I want to?

Comment: @Moti Thanks this could work, would you be able to provide example?

Comment: If you use a Cursor (linked above, you have multiple options), you can iterate through results one-by-one. Transform, save, then handle the next item. That way, you never need to have the entire database in memory. With a result set like this you should _not_ use `.toArray()` which would fetch all 3gb worth of results at once.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json